# VScode connect remote Jupyter server with headers

Tags: jupyter, vscode-extensions, jupyter-lab

I'd like to add headers when I connect to remote Jupyter server.
How can I deal with this?
Thanks
[Choose Existing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsTaL.png)

I put jupyterlab url without headers and it redirected to login page.